# how to place a file inside .bashrc

Tags: emacs

I am following a tutorial on the link https://github.com/birlrobotics/birl_baxter/wiki and I was told as folows:

**Finally, after doing catkin_make, place the newly created ~/ros/indigo/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash file inside .bashrc**

```
cd ~
emacs .bashrc
source ~/ros/indigo/rbx_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

When I run the command ***emacs .bashrc*** the emacs editor opens but I am not sure what I am expected to do after that .

Comment: Just use a different editor if you're unfamiliar with Emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial asks you to open your .bashrc file with the extensible editor Emacs by executing`emacs .bashrc`. Then you are supposed to add the line `source ~/ros/indigo/rbx_ws/devel/setup.bash` at the end of the file.
Then you exit the editor Emacs with the key stroke "C-x C-c" meaning you press the Control/CTRL key, hold it and then press first the 'x' key and then the 'c' key. After this you continue the tutorial.

Otherwise you can just:

`echo "source ~/ros/indigo/rbx_ws/devel/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc` in your terminal without using the editor Emacs.